# How to upload a sqlite db file to ftp server from android program

Tags: android, sqlite, ftp

APP crashed every time I invoke ftp write operation.

I have below 2 methods in a `Fragment`.

```
public void uploadData () {     


        String domain = "10.142.42.10";  // <<< will it work as it is private ip?
        String user = "xxxx";
        String password = "xxxx";
        String serverRoad = "Documents";

        File file = new File("/sdcard/bluetooth/NRC_jiten.pdf");
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftp.connect(InetAddress.getByName(domain));
            //ftp.connect(domain,21);
            ftp.login(user, password);

            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(serverRoad);
            ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftp.storeFile("jiten_pdf.pdf", buffIn);
            buffIn.close();

            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "err:" + e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}

public void uploadFileBackground () {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                uploadData();

            }
        }).start();


    }
```

Now, from an `Activity` I trigger `uploadFileBackground` upon a mouse click on a button.

Is there anything wrong with the code? I have referred this site, but not able to succeed.

TIA.

---

**LogCat**

```
            08-25 19:00:56.042  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.044  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.047  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.047  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.049  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.050  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.051  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.052  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.052  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.056  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.056  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.058  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 6774470
08-25 19:00:56.079  16119-16138/com.sbordolo.potholefinder D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-25 19:00:56.080  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ffc140, tid 16119
08-25 19:00:56.088  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
08-25 19:00:56.474  16119-16138/com.sbordolo.potholefinder D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ffc3c0, tid 16138
08-25 19:00:56.483  16119-16138/com.sbordolo.potholefinder I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-25 19:00:56.488  16119-16138/com.sbordolo.potholefinder D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-25 19:00:56.514  16119-16138/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-25 19:00:56.514  16119-16138/com.sbordolo.potholefinder W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3fdb4e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-25 19:00:56.844  16119-16119/com.sbordolo.potholefinder E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sbordolo.potholefinder.HomeScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{9052cc6 V.E..... R....... 0,0-1026,591} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.sbordolo.potholefinder.CoordinateClass.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(CoordinateClass.java:110)
            at com.sbordolo.potholefinder.CoordinateClass.onActivityCreated(CoordinateClass.java:66)
            at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2061)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:912)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1049)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1869)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:5985)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5992)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: You should provide your logcat. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Mauker, thanks for your reply. I ran the app in the handset. While compiling in the android studio,  I got logs as attached

Comment: I tried to ftp copy a pdf file, but no luck.

Comment: Your log seems incomplete.

Comment: Mauker, plz check now.

Comment: Are you trying to show a `Dialog` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, update your Google Play Services using the Google Play app. As you can see here:

```
Google Play services out of date.
```

It's outdated.

Secondly, don't use `Thread` like that to do your background stuff on Android, as

> (...) it violates the second rule of the single-threaded model: ***do not
>   access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread***.

Try to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), or [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

More information on threads [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), on services [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), and on Handler [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).

---

Now for your problem, you're getting this exception:

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sbordolo.potholefinder.HomeScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{9052cc6 V.E..... R....... 0,0-1026,591} that was originally added here
```

The `WindowLeaked` exceptions are most commonly thrown because of non dismissed `Dialog`s on the code.

And your logcat trace shows that a Dialog is trying to popup:

```
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
```

**EDIT:** So it was crashing because of your `Toast`. Remove it, or try the solutions above and you should be fine.

**Second edit:** As you mentioned, and just to leave the answer complete, your ftp server need to have the correct permissions set, so your program can write stuff in there. Your `chmod 777` can work, but **be careful** with that, as it leaves your server open for anyone to write there.

Comment: Is it anything to do with the ftp upload? I am using google play services for other stuff in the activity.

Comment: Sorry, I was updating the answer. It's not the problem, but you should get it updated ;)

Comment: :) Its ok, I will upload once I identify this problem of ftp upload!!

Comment: Can I use a nested class as async activity within a fragment?

Comment: Regarding the question on popup, I was using Toast within the thread.

Comment: Then I guess we found your problem. Kill the `Toast` and try again ;)

Comment: I removed that part of the code. Now the app is not crashing but I am not able to see the transferred file in the ftp server. I am not sure whether it works with "private ip" or not! The ftp server is reachable from the handset as I checked the same from a terminal emulator.

Comment: It might be reachable, but is it accessible? Can you access that server using any other ftp client?

Comment: yes, I can reach it & can do ftp operations from it. Does the app expects that the ftp server should be reachable via INTERNET? If so, then it won't work.

Comment: Did you remember to put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` on your manifest?

Comment: Yes, that is present. My doubt lies here, my FTP server won't be reachable via internet as it is private ip. The App has to use local wifi network to which it is connected. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If your IP is not reachable on the internet, then yes, you can only access it on your internal network.

Comment: Then, does FTPClient class works on private ip? I think it should not worry about whether an ip is public or private right? If it reachable and ftp server is running, that should be sufficient.

Comment: As far as I know, if it's reachable, it should work, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause, there was a permission issue which I found upon looking at the pcap file. FTP login was successful, but while client was trying to put the file, due to permission issue, it was failing! Made the directory permission to 777, fixed!

Thanks Mauker for helping me out on this.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a "green mark" on the side of the voting area of a question, just click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I implemented for my application.

```
public static String getDiretorioBackup() {

    String diretorio = "";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/" + "dir";
    }
    else {
        diretorio = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "dir";    
    }

    return diretorio;
}


public static FTPClient connnectFTP(String ip, String userName, String pass) throws Exception{   

        FTPClient mFtpClient = new FTPClient();  
        mFtpClient.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
        mFtpClient.connect( ip );

        boolean status = mFtpClient.login(userName, pass);  
        Log.e("login ftp:", String.valueOf(status));  

        return mFtpClient;
    } 


public static Boolean uploadFile(String email, String pathUpload, String guidStr) throws Exception
    {  
        FTPClient ftpClient = connnectFTP(Constantes.FTP, Constantes.FTP_USER, Constantes.FTP_PASS);

        if(ftpClient != null)
        {                   
            FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream( getDiretorioBackup() +"/"+ ConstantesBanco.DATABASE_NAME ); //antes de fazer o ftp é feita a cópia local  
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(ftpClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.setFileType(ftpClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


            boolean status = ftpClient.storeFile( pathUpload+fileName , srcFileStream);

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(status) + "- reply code:"+ ftpClient.getReplyCode()+" "+ftpClient.getReplyString());  
            srcFileStream.close();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

            return status;
        }
        else{
            throw new BackupFtpException(Constantes.ERRO_SERV_FTP);         
        }
    }
```